# Typescript - Write simultaneously in two textareas

Tags: javascript, typescript, cursor, textarea

I am currently working on a hex-editor displaying normal text in one textarea and hex in a second one.

What I want is to change the hex string, when the normal string gets edited and the other way around. As the hex string is always twice as long as the ASCII one, I can think of getting the selectionStart from the edited string and update the other string on keyup. 
I guess this would work, but it's not that nice.

The textareas use a two way binding, so displaying changes isn't that hard.

What I would prefer is to have two carets, one in every textarea and then just write simultaneously to both, if that is possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function do_this(val){

    
    document.getElementById('two').innerHTML=val.value;

}
```

```html
<textarea id="one" onkeyup="do_this(this)"></textarea>
<textarea id="two" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

Comment: As I said, this will work, but is not what I do prefer. But thanks anyway.